# generated Jointable is not updated in manytomany mapping while updating the entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I have two entities, One is user and another one is role.
User to role is an bidirectional manytomany mapping.
I have populated my db (postgres) with some predefined roles.

The user table looks like this

```
@Entity(name = "user_identity")
public class UserIdentity {
@Column(name = "user_identity_id", nullable = false, unique = true, 
updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy =  
"org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Id()
@JsonProperty("userIdentityId")
private String userIdentityId = null;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity= Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_identity_roles", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = 
"user_identity_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", 
referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();



/**
 * Returns the value of '<em><b>roles</b></em>' feature.
 *
 * <!-- begin-user-doc --> <!-- end-user-doc -->
 * 
 * @return the value of '<em><b>roles</b></em>' feature
 */
public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

/**
 * Sets the '{@link UserIdentity#getRoles() <em>roles</em>}' feature.
 *
 * <!-- begin-user-doc --> <!-- end-user-doc -->
 * 
 * @param newRoles the new value of the '{@link UserIdentity#getRoles() roles}'
 *                 feature.
 */
public void addRole(Role newRole) {
    this.roles.add(newRole);
    newRole.getUsers().add(this);
}
}
```

Roles table looks like this

```
public class Role{

@Id()
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = 
false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy ="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private String id = null;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles",, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore 
private List<UserIdentity> users = new ArrayList<UserIdentity>();



public List<UserIdentity> getUsers() {
    return users;
}


public void addUsers(UserIdentity newUser) {
    this.users.add(newUser);
}
}
```

While creating an user with roles, the user_identity_roles table (Join table) is updated with the userId and roleId.

updating an existing user with a new role is not working.
below is the code for updating an existing user with a new role.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public boolean updateRoleOfUser(String userId, String roleId) {

    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(roleId) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(userId)) {
        return false;
    }

    Optional<UserIdentity> existingUser = userRepository.findById(userId);

    if (!existingUser.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(userId, "User not found with this id");
    }

    UserIdentity oldUser = existingUser.get();

    Optional<Role> roleById = roleRepository.findById(roleId);

    if (!roleById.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(roleId, "role not found with this id");
    }

    Role role = roleById.get();

    oldUser.getRoles().add(role);
    UserIdentity newUserIdentity = userRepository.save(oldUser);

    role.getUsers().add(newUserIdentity);

    return newUserIdentity != null;
}
```

I have already tried to use Set instead of List. 
I am using spring data JpaRepository.

My Expected output would be to save the new role ids into the generated jointable.
It would be very helpful to have some pointers in this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the bidirectional mapping before the save. Role must be added to the user and user must be added to the role. Afterwards the save can be triggered. At the moment you are adding the role to the user, saving and then adding the user to the role.

**Edit:**
Or use the already defined method oldUser.addRole(role) which already does the bidirectional mapping.